# Boost.Asio SSL ungraceful close

Tags: boost, ssl, openssl, boost-asio

I am trying to handle SSL error scenarios where, for example, SSL async_handshake() is taking too long.
After some time (say 20sec) i want to close this connection (lowest_layer().close()).
I pass shared_ptr with connection object as a parameter to async_handshake(), so object still exists, eventually handshake handler is invoked and object gets destroyed.

But, still I'm getting sporadic crashes! Looks like after close() SSL is still trying to read or operate on read buffer.

So, the basic question - is it safe to hard close() SSL connection?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Typically the method I've used stop outstanding asynchronous operations on a socket is `socket::cancel` as described in the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/cancel/overload2.html). Their handlers will be invoked with `asio::error::operation_aborted` as the error parameter, which you'll need to handle somehow.

That said, I don't see a problem using `close` instead of `cancel`. Though it is difficult to offer much help or advice without some code to analyze.

---

Note that some Windows platforms have problems when canceling outstanding asynchronous operations. The [documentation has suggestions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/using.html) for portable cancelation if your application needs to support Windows.

Comment: This not helping in async_handshake case, at least for me.

Comment: @PSIAlt added a link to the docs about Windows platforms and limitations with `cancel()`

Comment: Thanks, but i got same trouble as OP on linux. Its easy to reproduce: setup async_handshake and setup deadline_timer for about 2-5miliseconds. On this timer i close underlying connection for `ssl::stream` using `lowest_layer().close()` and app coredumps inside `SSL_connect`.. Dunno how to fix that, just increased the timer for now